# awk command taking argument passed to function as value

Tags: bash, shell, kubernetes-helm

I'm writing helm testcase in shell script.

I have passed 3 arguments to this function. in awk '{print $2}' I want it to print the 2nd column value of previous grep output. But it's taking 2nd argument passed to function as input for $2.

Can anyone please help me to solve this?

```
function get_selector() {
    local cr_name=$1
    local cr_type=$2
    selector_name=$3
    echo "kubectl get $cr_type $cr_name -o yaml -n {{ .Release.Namespace }} | grep $selector_name | awk '{print $2}'"
    output = $(kubectl get $cr_type $cr_name -o yaml -n {{ .Release.Namespace }} | grep $selector_name | awk '{print $2}')
    echo $output
}
```

Comment: It'll be substituted in the `echo` command because it's in double-quotes (the single-quotes have no effect when they're in double-quotes themselves), but it shouldn't be in the actual `kubectl` command. This sort of thing is why it's better to use `set -x` to turn on command tracing (and `set +x` to turn it off). Is the actual command messed up, or just the echoed version? Also, is the `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` part supposed to be quoted, or is that replaced by a preprocessor before the shell interprets it?

Comment: `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` is something that could normally appear in a Helm chart template file; but in this context it probably needs to be an environment variable as well.  Don't forget to double-quote variable references like `"$cr_type"`; consider [`kubectl get -o jsonpath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/jsonpath/) over using `grep` and `awk` here.

Comment: @DavidMaze Do you know how the code flow works in helm test written in shell script?

Comment: Sorry, is this inside a Job or ConfigMap that's being run as a `helm test`?  That would in fact cause `{{ .Release.Namespace }}` to be replaced.  (I'd still double-quote it.)

Comment: The spaces on both sides of `=` are a syntax error. In isolation, the code you show works fine after we fix that (except, it's also a [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo), and also a useless `grep`). Going forward, try https://shellcheck.net/ before asking for human assistance.